# how to overcome CSVFormatter error on pandasai?

Tags: pandas, csv, openai-api

while trying to test Pandas AI I am having a consistent problem related with a CSVFormatter

my code is the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandasai import PandasAI
from pandasai.llm.openai import OpenAI


pandasAiTutorial = "my token"

import pandas as pd
from pandasai import PandasAI

# Sample DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "country": ["United States", "United Kingdom", "France", "Germany", "Italy", "Spain", "Canada", "Australia", "Japan", "China"],
    "gdp": [19294482071552, 2891615567872, 2411255037952, 3435817336832, 1745433788416, 1181205135360, 1607402389504, 1490967855104, 4380756541440, 14631844184064],
    "happiness_index": [6.94, 7.16, 6.66, 7.07, 6.38, 6.4, 7.23, 7.22, 5.87, 5.12]
})

# Instantiate a LLM
from pandasai.llm.openai import OpenAI
llm = OpenAI(api_token=pandasAiTutorial)

pandas_ai = PandasAI(llm)
pandas_ai(df, prompt='Which are the 5 happiest countries?')
```

the error reads:

"Unfortunately, I was not able to answer your question, because of the following error:\n\nCSVFormatter.**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'line_terminator'\n"